# IIS Tomcat connector, AJP configuration

Tags: iis, tomcat9, isapi, ajp

I setup ISAPI connector to have IIS web server communicate with Tomcat Servlet container. However I am getting an error while trying to access Tomcat application :

***Service Temporarily Unavailable!
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Tomcat/ISAPI/isapi_redirector/1.2.48***

In my "isapi-redirect.log" I am getting these messages :

***ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1724): (tomcat01) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=61)***

However Tomcat is up and running and "examples" application is accessible through "http://localhost:8080/examples/"

Here is my AJP Connector connector configuration in Tomcat's server.xml :

```
<Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               secretRequired="false"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

and here is an entry from "workers.properties":

```
worker.list=tomcat01
worker.tomcat01.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat01.host=localhost
worker.tomcat01.port=8009
```

I tried to change port to 8109 however it didn't change anything and I was getting the same error message in "isapi-redirect.log" pointing to the port 8009.
It looks like there is a problem with my AJP configuration. How do I need to configure it so an IIS request will be properly rooted to Tomcat?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/httpplatformhandler/httpplatformhandler-configuration-reference#tomcat Far easier approach than what you chose.

Comment: I am following these instructions :

https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html